# Getting variable from url, not being able to echo full string

Tags: php, url, variables, mod-rewrite, get

I have a dynamic url which looks like the following;

```
news/categories/s/23-brook-launch-new-zealand
```

the "23" is the article id and the "brook-launch-new-zealand" is the article title.

When I do:

```
echo $_GET['title'];
```

it only echos back: "brook" not the full string.

I am using mod_rewrite for my urls, code follows:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

How can I echo the full string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rewrite rule does not support dashes try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([^/]*) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

Answer (score 4):

You aren't matching against possible `-`s:

```
... ([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z\-]+) /news/...
                     ^^ You need to add these
```

So the full line would be:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z\-]+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex that you are using to match the title `([a-zA-Z]+)` only matches a set of leters (a-z) and does not include a dash (`-`) symbol. Perhaps that part of the regular expression should be: `(([a-zA-Z]+-?)+)`

Then your rewrite rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-(([a-zA-Z]+-?)+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$4 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

With your version, only the letters (a-zA-Z) are allowed in a title, so the regex doesn't match the dashes. The above should match the dashes, and also will allow numbers in the title (which I suspect you will want to allow).

You may even simply want to do:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-(.+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

...and allow *any* character in the title - which you can easily get away with, since the title is the last portion of the URL.